# Wire hanging loose on B&S small engine - is that normal?

Tags: ignition, small-engine

I have a relatively new Briggs & Stratton engine on a Cyclone Rake leaf vacuum. Engine model is 130G32-0184-F1. It's been running fine for several weeks. Today it will not start. I hear no sound that would indicate combustion, so I'm thinking no spark.

Upon inspection I found a wire on the back side hanging loose, right in front of an empty threaded hole. Did a connector of some kind fall off? Or is the wire not supposed to be connected (maybe for a factory test?)

[image: Unconnected wire]

Comment: I can't tell you about the wire. I can't see where it's coming from, though I do see that there is a clip there which is holding the wire in place, which means it should be there. I doubt there's anything missing from the hole as it appears there's not been anything in there ... ever. You need to pull the spark plug and see if there's spark to the plug (ground it first before pulling the starter cord). Also, you sure there's gas in it and that it's turned on? Is the on/off switch in the on position? Little stupid things will get you sometimes, lol.

Comment: The [product manual](https://www.briggsandstratton.com/na/en_us/support/results/_jcr_content/par/productmanuallisting.downloadmanual.80098889_A_LO.pdf.html) doesn't seem to show it. There is a [similar image](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0128/2336/3684/products/ycjcqvfkp8yrpu7yctgu_grande.jpg?v=1587621813) where the wire is also unconnected, and with the unused hole nearby (and an additional wire goes to a chromed part that yours does not seem to have).

Comment: @WeatherVane - The second image is most likely a generator engine, with the part in the block being a low oil sensor.

Answer (score 1):

Cyclone Rake tech support confirmed that the wire is unused - it's used in other application of the engine.

Based on that I took @Paulster2's suggestion to check little things. It was just flooded. Left the air cleaner off overnight to dry out carb Started fine.